# Vertically Stretch List Items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a phonegap application. I have the following:

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Three <br>a Half</li>
</ul>
```

How can I make the `<li>` elements stretch vertically and fill the whole height of the page given that this needs to be dynamic so that it adapts to other viewports. The text inside the `<li>` elements needs to be vertically centred and supports multiple lines.

Is there any clean way of doing this?

Comment: First you say stretch, then you say vertically centered. Which one do you want?

Comment: @David both, the `<li>` vertically stretched to fit the viewport and the `content` inside the `<li>` vertically centred and supports multi-lines.

Comment: does phonegap play well with `display: table-cell`?  If it does this might work: http://jsfiddle.net/6z3q35x0/1

Comment: @JosephMarikle I think it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using the `display: table` family of CSS3 rules.  They'll be dynamic and maintain full height spacing if done correctly:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

ul li {
    display: table-row;
}

ul li a { /* assuming an anchor child.  Can be anything */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 1em 3em;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6z3q35x0/1/

Comment: I know phonegap has no issues with this. But does Safari Mobile or Chrome/Android Browser and IE10+ Hybrid have any issues with display:table; ?

Comment: @user1027620 [Yes, it should work on those (click "Show all")](http://caniuse.com/#search=table)

Comment: Great, thanks. Do you know of a way to automatically fix the anchor text according to a % of the container size (which is now variable)?

Comment: Yes I do!  You can use the `vw` or `vh` units of measure instead of `px` and `em`.  This stands for "viewport width" and "viewport height".  I think I remember there being some issues with IE on that one though, and `vw` is more widely supported than `vh` ([see here](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw)).  You can see this in action using `vh` in [this updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6z3q35x0/3/).  If you resize the result window height, you can see the text change in size based on the viewport.  Careful though.  This can result in really tiny text. Could add min-height media query to help that.

Comment: after experimenting with this. It seems when I have equal heights on the `<li>`'s and a `<br>` somewhere in the content they don't maintain the same height.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I forgot to explain something (my bad) is it possible to maintain 5 items only in a single viewport? In a way that the first five items fill the viewport height and other lis have the same height as the first five but are displayed after scrolling?

Comment: One last thing, I've added a height:20% on the `<li>` but there seems to be extra space on the bottom...

Comment: @user1027620 Well, unfortunately that makes my solution completely incompatible.  The table tries its best to fill up that space, so there isn't really a way to go backwards and say "fill up the viewport with 5 or fill all remaining space with what you have".  I believe I will have to delete my answer.

Comment: It's a working solution for the question I asked. It was my bad that I forgot to add additional details. Please keep it as I think it's the best answer for the question asked :) - I think it's a solution for other readers.

Comment: I asked another question with more details btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723596/flexible-custom-layout-with-css-possibly-js-if-needed

Comment: That makes sense.  Maybe it will help whoever searches for this problem.  I've tried a few tests to see what I could come up with, but this is as far as I got with it: http://jsfiddle.net/6z3q35x0/9/

Comment: The demo you provided actually looks awesome, but adding more lis would change all the heights - really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JavaScript solution, which will give the `height`s according to the viewport's `height`.

#### Forcing `ul` to take the entire viewport's height:

<kbd>**[Demo on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Lfynmk/8/)**</kbd>

```js
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
function doMath() {
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].style.height = window.innerHeight / li.length + 'px';
  }
}
doMath();
window.onresize = doMath;
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  background: rosybrown;
}
span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
li:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: plum;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>One</span></li>
  <li><span>Two</span></li>
  <li><span>Three</span></li>
  <li><span>Three<br />a Half</span></li>
  <li><span>Four</span></li>
  <li><span>Five<br />a Half</span></li>
  <li><span>Six</span></li>
</ul>
```

---

#### Forcing `li`s to take the entire viewport's height:

<kbd>**[Demo on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Lfynmk/9/)**</kbd>

```js
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
function doMath() {
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
  }
}
doMath();
window.onresize = doMath;
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  background: rosybrown;
}
span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
li:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: plum;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>One</span></li>
  <li><span>Two</span></li>
  <li><span>Three</span></li>
  <li><span>Three<br />a Half</span></li>
  <li><span>Four</span></li>
  <li><span>Five<br />a Half</span></li>
  <li><span>Six</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This can be achieved with CSS only... Why should you use a JS solution... I'm not saying it's bad or anything but can you explain please? I mean, doesn't CSS render faster?

Comment: @user1027620 -"_doesn't CSS render faster?_" - The JavaScript code is not that big, it wouldnt make any difference. Btw, I provided a JavaScript solution because you have added a JavaScript tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I forgot to explain something (my bad) is it possible to maintain 5 items only in a single viewport? In a way that the first five items fill the viewport height and other lis have the same height as the first five but are displayed after scrolling?

Comment: @user1027620 - Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I'm making this a bit more complex, but is it possible to add a class to the first item and make it fixed?

Comment: @user1027620 - Yes that is possible as well. You just have to overwrite its properties.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your question: the first is to force the `<ul>` element to stretch to fill the viewport, and the second is to vertically and horizontally center the `<li>` content. However, the centering requires modifications to your markup. We can wrap all the content in `<li>` using `<div>` elements.

For centering, we can use CSS3 flexbox for that. **This would be a JS-free solution**, although it enjoys less cross-browser support. For viewport size, we can use the `vw` and `vh` units respectively.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
li div {
  
}

/* For stylistics only */
li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
<li><div>One</div></li>
<li><div>Two</div></li>
<li><div>Three</div></li>
<li><div>Three <br>a Half</div></li>
</ul>
```

---

However, there might be situations where using CSS flexbox and viewport units are not ideal — iOS7, for example, has a well-documented rendering bug that does not calculate `vh` properly. In this case, we might have to rely on JS instead. The height of each `<li>` is simply divided by the number of `<li>`s present in the container.

```js
var calcHeight = function() {
  var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

  var li = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
  for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
    li[i].style.height = (h/li.length)+'px';
  }
}

calcHeight();
window.onresize = calcHeight();
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
li div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li><div>One</div></li>
  <li><div>Two</div></li>
  <li><div>Three</div></li>
  <li><div>Three <br>a Half</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your answer makes sense, maybe I've explained it wrong. I need the `<ul>` to be the vh and vw size and the `<li>`'s stretched inside.

Comment: With the flexbox solution above, the `li` needs to have `align-items: stretch;` set instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to add height 100% to body and html, try this

```
<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
li {
   height: 25%;
    display: table-row;
}
li div{
    height: 25%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
```

Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/d80xw55e/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're allowing Javscript, this is pretty easy, I'm just having trouble getting the bullet point right. Hopefully you won't be using that though?

```js
function liH(){
  var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  var liHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0) / lis.length;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; ++i){
    var spanH = spans[i].getBoundingClientRect().height;
    lis[i].style.paddingTop = ((liHeight - spanH) / 2) + "px";
    lis[i].style.paddingBottom = lis[i].style.paddingTop;
    //spans[i].style.top = -(spanH / 4) + "px"
  }
}

liH();
window.onresize = liH;
```

```css
li {background:#eee;margin-bottom:5px;}
span {position:relative;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>elem1</span></li>
  <li><span>elem2</span></li>
  <li><span>elem<br />3</span></li>
</ul>
```

The reason the view is not exact is because of the padding on the top that won't remove, and because of the 5px margin which I put to distinguish the elements.