# Flexible Custom Layout with CSS (possibly JS if needed)

Tags: javascript, html, css

As per the attached image. I am trying to make a `<ul>` that contains multiple items. However, I want the first five items to always fill the viewport height and if there are more than five items I need the rest to have the same height as the first five `<li>`'s.

As per li number 4 in the image, there maybe be a nested `<ul>` that can fill the width having multiple `<li>`'s.

The text inside all `<li>`s needs to be vertically centered and supports multi-line while retaining the same height as the other elements.

NOTE: Any other lis below the fold need to have the same height as the initial first five. (Even if there are less than five elements at first, they shouldn't fill the full height. Only when there are five they complete the full page height.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
My previous question was not full and I missed some explanations: [Vertically Stretch List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715958/vertically-stretch-list-items) I am using the CSS only solution (for now) which doesn't work as needed.

Thanks.[image]

CODE Used:

```css
ul.navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
ul.navigation li {
    display: table-row;
}
ul.navigation li a {
    font-size:1.8em;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 1em 1.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: would you be able to kindly post the code you have worked on thus far?

Comment: You also need to include what browsers you'll be supporting. `vh` and flexbox should an easy no-js solution if you can forget about IE. Also consider that this will look odd in a horizontal orientation.

Comment: @fontophilic This is for a phonegap application targeting modern mobile browsers. So iOS, Android and Windows Phone. (It's just portrait mode)

Comment: Part of the problem, which was posted in a separate question, was the issue of completely filling up the viewport height with the items.  Here is a fiddle that I had put together for testing purposes.  If anyone can use it, it's available: http://jsfiddle.net/6z3q35x0/9/ (it went through various revisions).  The problem is that you can't just show 5 items with a 100% height `display:table` element.

Comment: Is it accurate so say that the requirement for your `<li>` height is that it is always 20% of the viewport? The way that you've described that requirement is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the heights, one approach would be to use the `vh` keyword, which is 1% of the height of the viewport. It's only valid in IE9 up, but as I'm guessing this is a mobile screenshot, you should be ok.

You should also consider using flexbox, which works fine in mobile browsers, and it allows you to do vertical centering without all the messiness of `display:table`.

```
ul{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width:24em;
}
li{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content:space-around;
    align-items:center;
}
li > div {
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink:1;
    max-width: 50%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
li:nth-child(even){
    background: gray;
}
ul > li {
    height: 20vh;
}
```

Here's a dabblet: 
http://result.dabblet.com/gist/78afacb7e747b7e24e62/ba0f81dc9278ec743c58027e995a0f6c381329b8

http://dabblet.com/gist/78afacb7e747b7e24e62

Comment: What about iOS < 8 ? And the nested horizontal splits?

Comment: The nested horizontal splits are fine if you're using flexbox. you'd set the interior li to flex-direction: row, and then you'd do the centering on the divs. 

I updated the dabblet to reflect this. 

flexbox is supported in iOS7. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

If you use a CSS preprocessor that has a compatibility support library, you should be fine with older flexbox browers, too.

Comment: If you use Stylus as a CSS preprocessor, there's a library called Nib that comes with it that offers fantastic flexbox support all the way back to Android 2.4

Comment: Thanks for the update. however, I cannot see it n the dabblet :/

Comment: I added an updated dabblet link, which includes not only the result, but the code.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for being too annoying maybe. But in the latest dabblet I can see six items in the viewport instead of five, is this the correct solution? The previous one showed five only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67995/discussion-between-paceaux-and-user1027620).

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this could point you in a direction: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/10/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="section">My content here</div>
    <div class="section">My content here</div>
    <div class="section">My content here</div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="sub-section">Half Content</div>
        <div class="sub-section" style="margin-left:-4px;">Half Content</div> (EDITED)
    </div>
    <div class="section">My content here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.section {
    height: 20vh;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: block;
}
.sub-section {
    width: 50%
    display: inline-block;
}
```

EDIT: new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/11/ compliments of hungerstar's insight

Comment: Why is it 49.7% instead of 50% -  Just trying to understand :)

Comment: Also I think this breaks on iOS < 8 -> https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/36

Comment: @user1027620 it says it was resolved, and because theres a small space between the sub-sections that pushes 50% to the next line, probably something to do with the spacing of divs, i usually use bootstrap when dealing with grid spacings instead of tables

Comment: Do you recommend I add bootstrap to the solution? However, i don't need any of the styling it provides...

Comment: um, i dont think its necessary to add bootstrap, i just personally like the clean-ness it provides

Comment: adding `20vh` to the `<li>`s seems to resolve the height issues... But It needs to be supported on iOS 6/7 so I'm not sure about this.

Comment: The reason you cannot use `width: 50%;` is because you are using `display: inline-block` on those elements. Any space between the elements will be treated as a single white space, like those separating my words right now. Either float them or place comments in-between `</div><!-- --><div>`, which is kind of dirty.

Comment: Not sure adding a set amount of margin is the best approach as you cannot guarantee that it will always work. Besides, it feels a bit hack-ish like using comments to solve the issue in my previous comment. I would just float the sub sections like so: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/12/

Answer (score 0):

I went for the 'calculate height with js' instead of vh. I think vh is more elegant but if you need more support you're going to have to use js.

http://jsbin.com/huroqiliba/1/edit?html,css,js,output

I'm using flexbox for the vertical centering of text and the columns. Flexbox has pretty solid support at this point. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this does not ensure the first five elements fill the viewport height. And that all elements have equal heights regardless of their content...

Comment: if one item is taller than viewheight / 5 do you want all items to grow to tallest height so they always stay equal height?

Comment: No I need to force all parent `<li>`s to have vh/5 as a maximum regardless of their content (so that only five lis can fill the viewport at one time)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be using `vh` and flexbox in this solution to avoid doing any js. If you need to support older browsers, consider using a pollyfill such as: https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly and https://github.com/doctyper/flexie which work very well with Modernizr.

## HTML

```
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li class="one"><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a href="#">Two<br> Overflow: hidden keeps this long li at an equal height, but obviously be smart about this and don't cut off your content with a huge font size or long text.</a></li>
    <li class="three"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li class="four-a"><a href="#">Four and</a></li><li class="four-b"><a href="#">a Half</a></li></ul><li class="five"><a href="#">Five</a></li>
      <li class="fold"><a href="#">Fold</a></li>
      <li class="fold"><a href="#">Fold</a></li>
      <li class="fold"><a href="#">Fold</a></li>
    </ul>
```

## CSS

```
ul.navigation, ul.navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

ul.navigation ul li {
  display:inline-flex;
  width:50%;

}

ul.navigation ul{
  display:flex;
}

ul.navigation li a {
    font-size:1.8em;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 1.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;

}

ul.navigation li{
  overflow: hidden; 
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.one {background-color:lightgray;}
.two {background-color:tomato;}
.three {background-color:palegreen;}
.four-a {background-color:indianred;}
.four-b {background-color:palevioletred;}
.five {background-color:papayawhip;}
.fold{background-color:black;}
```

Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/fontophilic/pen/yyVNQd?editors=110